# Titles above bootstrap wells causing mis-alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get these two wells on the same row to align correctly. I want the titles and the wells to be on the same line. This is my code, but its on Bootply as well.. Here [Link to Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/YJ5dVlwZc6#)

Plus I can't get the "Help Credentials" title to left align with the well..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-1"> 
   <h2>Add your credentials</h2>
   <div class="col-md-5 well">Stuff</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
 <h2>Help credentials</h2>
   <div class="col-md-5 well col-md-offset-1">
        Stuff
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you much..

Comment: Solution moved to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nesting columns without the required rows. Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                 <h2>Add your Amazon credentials</h2>

                <div class="well">Stuff</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1">
                 <h2>Help credentials</h2>

                <div class="well">stuff</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/CLuuewZBWu)**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting